# Bigrquery library in R doesn't upload the data and returns no error. Getting application call back when press stop

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I am trying to upload the data into Google Big Query using Bigrquery package in R - I was able to successfully run the script before, but today it failed with no changes within a script.

Please see the script below:

```
library(bigrquery)
df = mtcars
    bq_auth(email = "my@email.com")
    job <- insert_upload_job("project-id", "dataset", "table name", df)
```

When I run the script, it shows that it is working, but the upload takes an infinite amount of time. When I stop the upload process, I am getting below message:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Operation was aborted by an application callback
```

Surprisingly, I was able to run the above script successfully before, and it is only today that it failed (I haven't changed anything). Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: @chinsoon12 the account went through authorization successfully. Also, I am able to request the data from BQ Console as well.

Comment: maybe check the logs on gcp?

Comment: hmm..seems like I don't have sufficient rights

Answer (score 1):

`insert_upload_job` is a deprecated function. They suggest changing it to using one of the `api_perform` functions.

Try this:

```
bq_tbl <- bq_table("project-id", "dataset", "table name")

bq_table_create(bq_tbl)

job <- bq_table_upload(bq_tbl,values=df,quiet = FALSE)
```